# Folders in "Show Applications" get deleted after restart

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

I create a folder with applications, after the restart the folder gets deleted, how do I keep the folder intact after restart/shutdown?

| Before restart | After restart |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |